# Is there a C# language construct/framework object to apply a function to each line of a file?

Tags: c#

What I'm looking for is something along these lines:

```
var f = UsefulFileObject(@"c:\temp.log");
f.ForEachLine( (line) => line.Trim() );
```

After that I'd expect each line in the file to be trimmed.

Is there such an object in the framework already or should I start making my own one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After seeing several wrong solutions using `ForEach` on an **immutable type** such as `string`, I guess I'll post my own.

This will actually read and write the mentioned file. Still, it's for smallish files only as the entire contents will be in memory*.

```
string filename = @"C:\testfile.txt";
string[] fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
fileLines = Array.ConvertAll(fileLines, l => l.Trim());
File.WriteAllLines(filename, fileLines);
```

In the real world, you'd probably want to write to a different file first and rename it to the original file after the operation has succeeded. Otherwise parts of the file could be lost if something went wrong halfway writing.

**Ad memory usage:**
Actually, the file will be in memory *twice* momentarily. You could solve that by using a regular `for` loop instead of any fancy extension methods and lambda expressions. I'll skip that excercise and go straight to the 'proper' way of doing this for larger files:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"D:\infile.txt"))
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"D:\outfile.txt"))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(line.Trim());
    }
}

// Some File.Move(..) usage to rename the files
```

**Implementing "ForEachLine"**:
If you want to implement a helper method that does what you describe, you could hide the ugly renaming logic in there.

The method signature would be something like:

```
public void ForEachLine(Func<string, string> func)
```

and the line doing the writing would just be:

```
writer.WriteLine(func(line));
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't modify a text file in place (well, obviously you *can*, but it's just freaking hard), such an object would basically be centered around a read-modify-write system.

Comment: Agreed. I wouldn't attempt to modify things in place, ever. In this case, the operation is guaranteed to make your file more compact, which is more or less a requirement. There is no reliable way to recover from failure, etc.

Answer (score -1):

For rather small files use File.ReadAllLines(filename).ForEach( l=> l.Trim() )

Comment: Almost. The ReadAllLines method returns a string array and you must create a List<T> to use the ForEach method

Comment: Since a string array implements IEnumerable<T> you could use File.ReadAllLines(filename).Select( l=> l.Trim() )

Comment: Look at MSDN: Array.ForEach<(Of <(T>)>)

Comment: @Denis Troller: You should be explaining that that won't modify anything, and hence isnt as 'foreach'-like in behaviour as one might expect

Comment: @Dewfy: `Array.Foreach` is not an extension method, so you'd actually have to write `Array.Foreach(File.Read...`. Secondly, it will not actually do anything useful, since there is no output?

Comment: @Thorarin: For enlisted sample just add writing to output in delegate:

StreamWriter out = new ...

l=> out.WriteLine( l.Trim())

Answer (score -1):

You have the System.IO.File.ReadAllLines() method that returns an string[] (array of strings).

The array can then be used with a foreach loop of you can convert it to a List and use the ForEach(Action) method.

So this should work:

```
string[] logLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\temp.log");
logLines.ToList().ForEach(l => l.Trim());
```

Comment: Same problem here: `logLines` is not actually modified at all.

Comment: Good point. I didn't notice that he wanted to write it back to the file.